# Should I ask for a meeting schedule?

Tags: united-kingdom, meetings, scheduling

The team I'm part of, will meet our stakeholders (our internal clients who also represent our external clients) in a few days time.

The stakeholders are based in another country, the UK, more precisely. Our team is based in continental Europe.

Our team will spend the day there, meeting the stakeholders to see what they want in term of the software we are building.

However, since the meeting has been planned, we did not have any specific schedule of the meetings we are going to attend and who we are going to meet in these meetings.

Example: From 9Am to 12Pm, we are going to meet the head of UK IT, from 1PM to 4PM, we are going the UK business holders.

Would it be considered as rude to ask for such schedule to our stakeholders?

Update

---

This is the answer I gave to my stakeholders

`Not sure how would you like to organize the day but it would be great if we can show our presentation to anyone who are/will be involved in project XYZ and have a discussion around the topics we will raised.`

Comment: Hi @PagMax I made an update. It was more of an example.

Comment: You mention "The team I'm part of"  but role what do you play with this team? If you aren't responsible for planning the trip, then asking for too many details may be rude.

Comment: Hi @mhoran_psrep, your comment is insightful. I'm the tech lead and the de facto technical pm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > Would it be considered as rude to ask for such schedule to our stakeholders?

I do not think it would be considered as rude. It seems reasonable to know the schedule for your day. As long as you ask it nicely instead of demanding it or pushing for it, there is nothing wrong in asking.

Answer (score 3):

> *Should I ask for a meeting schedule?*

Yes, you should.

> *Would it be considered as rude to ask for such schedule to our stakeholders?*

No, rather quite the opposite. Any meeting, needs to be planned properly. No one has infinite amount of time, and we need to manage our work / priorities accordingly. A defined schedule helps us manage our work, thereby utilizing the time in an efficient way.

Please go ahead and ask for a schedule. Also, keep in mind, almost all schedules are *practically* tentative, so be flexible enough to accommodate any last minute changes - should not be a surprise.